# get date without time from athena table using s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

As i have the table in athena with multiple columns. In that table one of the column named such as date_col with below format.

```
  date_col

 1/13/2022 3:00:16 PM
 1/13/2022 3:00:13 PM
 1/13/2022 2:00:16 PM
 1/13/2022 2:15:16 PM
```

From the above date_col records, I want to get the only date without time part.

Here it is i am using the query :

```
select date_col, date_format(date_col, '%m/%d/%Y') from 'test'.sample_table'
```

But getting below error like :

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:25: Unexpected parameters (varchar, varchar(8)) for function date_format. Expected: date_format(timestamp with time zone, varchar(x)) , date_format(timestamp, varchar(x))
```

Required format should be like:

```
  date_col

 1/13/2022 
 1/13/2022 
 1/13/2022 
 1/13/2022
```

I used different ways to get that result. But, I couldn't get the required format. Can you please help me for that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the date_format function

```
select date_col ,date_format(date_col, '%m/%d/%Y') FROM <table_name>;
```

Comment: I tried it. But it's not working

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: it's throwing the error like :  Only one sql statement is allowed. Got: select date_col ,date_format(date_col, '%m/%d/%Y'); FROM "test"."sample_table"

Comment: @user98 remove the semicolon before "FROM" and then execute

Comment: @Jijo Alexander, Still i am getting the same error. After using your answer

Comment: @Jijo Alexander, error like : SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:24: Unexpected parameters (varchar, varchar(8)) for function date_format. Expected: date_format(timestamp with time zone, varchar(x)) , date_format(timestamp, varchar(x)).